# ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I am unable to install the Anaconda package

getting error

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'.
Rolling back transaction: ...working... done
```

Following logs

```
  zipp               pkgs/main/noarch::zipp-2.2.0-py_0
  zlib               pkgs/main/win-64::zlib-1.2.11-h62dcd97_3
  zstd               pkgs/main/win-64::zstd-1.3.7-h508b16e_0


Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... WARNING conda.core.envs_manager:register_env(52): Unable to register environment. Path not writable or missing.
  environment location: E:\Anaconda
  registry file: C:\Users\Sam--pc\.conda\environments.txt
done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'.
Rolling back transaction: ...working... done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0
location of failed script: E:\Anaconda\Scripts\.qt-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:         1 file(s) copied.

stderr: The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.

return code: 1

()

Delete file: E:\Anaconda\pkgs\env.txt
Output folder: E:\Anaconda\conda-meta
Extract: history
Creating Anaconda3 menus...
Execute: "E:\Anaconda\pythonw.exe" -E -s "E:\Anaconda\Lib\_nsis.py" mkdirs
Running post install...
Execute: "E:\Anaconda\pythonw.exe" -E -s "E:\Anaconda\Lib\_nsis.py" post_install
Execute: "E:\Anaconda\pythonw.exe" -E -s "E:\Anaconda\pkgs\.cio-config.py" "D:\Software\Software\Softwares\Anaconda3-2020.02-Windows-x86_64.exe"
Created uninstaller: E:\Anaconda\Uninstall-Anaconda3.exe
Completed
```

I have tried reinstalling with admin rights still the issue prevails
Windows 10

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5usQ.png

Comment: Hi, Did you solve this? I faced this today on windows as well!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried many ways, this below one worked for me

the (base) in anaconda file has no environment variable set.

you can know what envs is set by typing
"**conda info**"

if it shows

-*active environment : none*-

then,

create a new envs as below

**conda create --name environment_name_of_your_own**

after following the steps

**conda activate environment_name_of_your_own**

from *(base)* , it changes to *(environment_name_of_your_own)*

you can run your commands from here now, it will work mostly.

it worked for me.

AlSO,

change your PC/Laptop *

> Environment Variables -> User Variables -> TEMP (double click and
> change directory to) -> C:/Temp

- 

also
*

> TMP (double click and change directory to) -> C:/Temp

- 

MY "**code info**"

active environment : D:\miniconda_envi_setup_here\some_folder\env
active env location : D:\miniconda_envi_setup_here\some_folder\env
shell level : 3
user config file : C:\Users\PC Dell.condarc
populated config files : C:\Users\PC Dell.condarc
conda version : 4.9.2
conda-build version : not installed
python version : 3.9.1.final.0
virtual packages : __cuda=11.1=0
__win=0=0
__archspec=1=x86_64
base environment : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3  (read only)
channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
package cache : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\pkgs
C:\Users\PC Dell.conda\pkgs
C:\Users\PC Dell\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
envs directories : C:\Users\PC Dell.conda\envs
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs
C:\Users\PC Dell\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
platform : win-64
user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.25.0 CPython/3.9.1 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
administrator : False
netrc file : None
offline mode : False